# Python does not recognize Pandas functions

Tags: python, pandas

So I installed pandas and I can run these first two lines no problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

But this line:

```
pd.read_csv('train.csv', header=0)
```

gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'read_csv'
```

Is there something wrong with the module?

I am running Python 2.7.5 with Mac OS X  10.9.2

Your input is appreciated!

EDIT: I was running a file named pandas.py, which is the same name as the 'pandas' module, hence the error.

Comment: Did you perhaps create your own file called `pandas.py`?

Comment: What is the result of `import pandas` followed by `pandas.__version__`?  Note that there are two underscores on each side of version.  The stable version of [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/getpandas.html) as of Feb 2014 is `0.13.1`

Comment: Yes you are correct BrenBarn! >_<

I renamed it and now it runs fine...phew!

Comment: use interactive python ipython